# Unable to create DF from mounted s3 bucket in databricks

Tags: python, databricks

I'm not sure where exactly i'm going wrong here, so i have three buckets in aws named `<username>.pin, <username>.user, <username>.geo`

Firstly, I added my aws creditional onto databricks then

```
# pyspark functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
# URL processing
import urllib

# Define the path to the Delta table
delta_table_path = "dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/authentication_credentials"

# Read the Delta table to a Spark DataFrame
aws_keys_df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)

# Get the AWS access key and secret key from the spark dataframe
ACCESS_KEY = aws_keys_df.select('Access key ID').collect()[0]['Access key ID']
SECRET_KEY = aws_keys_df.select('Secret access key').collect()[0]['Secret access key']
# Encode the secrete key
ENCODED_SECRET_KEY = urllib.parse.quote(string=SECRET_KEY, safe="")

# AWS S3 bucket name
AWS_S3_BUCKET_GEO = "s3://user-12e255fc4fcd-bucket/topics/12e255fc4fcd.geo/partition=0/"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_PIN = "s3://user-12e255fc4fcd-bucket/topics/12e255fc4fcd.pin/partition=0/"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_USER = "s3://user-12e255fc4fcd-bucket/topics/12e255fc4fcd.user/partition=0/"
# Mount name for the bucket
MOUNT_NAME_GEO = "/mnt/mount_name/geo"


MOUNT_NAME_PIN = "/mnt/mount_name/pin"
MOUNT_NAME_USER = "/mnt/mount_name/user"
# Source url
SOURCE_URL_GEO = "s3n://{0}:{1}@{2}".format(ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_S3_BUCKET_GEO)
SOURCE_URL_PIN = "s3n://{0}:{1}@{2}".format(ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_S3_BUCKET_PIN)
SOURCE_URL_USER = "s3n://{0}:{1}@{2}".format(ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_S3_BUCKET_USER)
# Mount the drive
dbutils.fs.mount(SOURCE_URL_GEO, MOUNT_NAME_GEO)
dbutils.fs.mount(SOURCE_URL_PIN, MOUNT_NAME_PIN)
dbutils.fs.mount(SOURCE_URL_USER, MOUNT_NAME_USER)
```

This seems to have mounted it fine but when i try to read the associated json files

```
file_location_geo = "dbfs:/mnt/mount_name/geo/*.json"
file_type = "json"

# Ask Spark to infer the schema
infer_schema = "true"
# Read in JSONs from mounted S3 bucket
df_geo = spark.read.format(file_type) \
.option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
.load(file_location_geo)
```

I get the error of invalid mount expection